# ¿Que problemas puede causar el utilizar funciones obsoletas de javascript?

Tags: javascript, funciones

Tengo la siguiente duda, ¿supone algún problema utilizar funciones obsoletas de javascript?

Como por ejemplo utilizar las funciones "escape" y "unescape" en vez de "encodeURI" y "decodeURI".

Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generalmente cuando una función en cualquier API se considera obsoleta, debemos evitarla porque:

- Hay razones de peso por la que sus creadores (o mantenedores) la han marcado como obsoleta: funcionalidad incorrecta o poco intuitiva, fallo en el propio diseño que no se puede solucionar sin romper la retro-compatibilidad, rendimiento muy bajo...
- Depende de cada caso, pero es posible que la funcionalidad desaparezca al ser su sustituto aceptado por los usuarios.

La funcion escape() fue dividida en dos porque había dos escenario posibles: una URI o un componente de una URI. En cada caso hay que tratar la cadena de manera diferente para evitar problemas, lo que no puedes hacer con una única función.

Comment: El problema que estoy teniendo es que la función encodeURI() no me está haciendo lo mismo que escape(), ya que con escape si que me muestra las comillas simples (supongo que las escapará con \') pero con encodeURI esto no me lo hace.

Answer (score 4):

El problema es que, aunque los navegadores aún las soporten, en cualquier momento pueden dejar de soportarlas debido a que ya no pertenecen al estándar.

Así que, aunque ahora te vaya a funcionar sin problemas en cualquier navegador, es muy probable que en un futuro próximo alguno de ellos (o todos) dejen de soportarlo.

Comment: Como siempre despejándome las dudas y problemas. Muchas Gracias !!!!

Comment: Por norma, siempre uso las que no están obsoletas. Lo que ya estaba hecho, dependiendo de lo que me va a costar hacer el cambio y si entra dentro de presupuesto lo dejo como está o lo cambio

Comment: Tengo sí o sí que utilizar escape() ya que encondeURI y encondeURIComponent no me "codifican" o "escapan" la comilla simple. No hay ninguna manera de hacer algo con la comilla simple?

Comment: Pero ¿en qué caso lo estás utilizando? Estos métodos efectivamente no codifican las comillas simples pero sí las dobles. Dependiendo del caso de uso podría buscarse una solución alternativa.